# swiftでバイナリデータの読み込み（バイトオーダー対策）

Tags: swift, swift3

iOSでは、バイトオーダーは、ビックエディアンみたいなのですが、
x86系のソフトのデータを、iOS読み込むとき、何等か方法があるのでしょうか。

Comment: takabosoft さんの書かれているように、現在のiOSが走るプラットフォームはSimulator(x86/x64)でも実機(ARM/ARM64)もリトルエンディアンです。(古いARMではエンディアンが選べたりするんですが、iOS機器ではリトルエンディアンです。)ただ、同じリトルエンディアンだからと言ってネイティブエンディアンのままでデータの読み書きを行うようなことは絶対にせず、ファイル定義や電文仕様ではバイトオーダーをきっちり明記した上で、ネイティブエンディアンのままでデータの読み書きを行わないようにする、と言うのが正しいバイトオーダー対策と言うことになるでしょう。例えばインターネットプロトコルで言うところの「ネットワークオーダー」はビッグエンディアン相当のバイト順なわけですが、x86でもその順序で通信しますし、正しく保存されたデータならビッグエンディアンであったPowerPC時代のMacのデータが現在のx86版Macでも読み込めたりします。

Comment: ようするに、自身のアプリで保存するエディアンを決定し統一し、CPU依存での保存をしないようにという解釈でよろしいでしょうか。ファイル定義や電文仕様への明記とは、開発アプリのソースでのコメント記述、ドキュメント類に記述するということでしょうか。実際、現在swift言語の勉強中で、iOSでの開発は初めてで、現在文書レベルの理解なので、解釈間違っていませんでしょうか？

Comment: はい、その通りです。「ファイル定義や電文仕様への明記」に関しては、すべての開発者(未来の自分を含む)の間で共有できる方法であればどのようなドキュメント(コメント類を含む)にするかはプロジェクトごとに決められれば良いと思います。読みにくい長文コメントを正しく解釈していただけていると思っています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下のようなコードをiPadのシミューレーター、実機両方で実行してみましたが、

```
var hoge = UInt32(0x1234ABCD)
print(NSData(bytes: &hoge, length: 4))
```

<cdab3412>と表示されたので、リトルエンディアンです。